# How to set position of post when you get data from rss feed?

Tags: wordpress, rss

Greetings from me !!

I want to make a when you publish the post then we have migrated that post in another site. but I want to post on the specific position like 3, 5 and etc..

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

yeh it's possible to write this query but you should use code for this

please read out article and then try

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-rss-feeds-in-wordpress/